# Retrieve all DOM elements in WebUI in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

Is there a way to retrieve all DOM elements in Katalon Studio so that I can execute actions with them randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
import org.openqa.selenium.By

WebUI.openBrowser('forum.katalon.com')
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"))
```

Try this and see if it helps.

Comment: I figured it out by doing something similar but using By.tagName("*"). But thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing with mobile?

Comment: Not sure. Haven't used Katalon for mobile testing. Try using Mobile.openBrowser() and keep the rest as is and post back.